# Attempting to save transient entity from dropdown list jsp hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, jpa

Trying to save child entity containing 2 existing parents in the DB ( user and type , the user works fine) , i don't know why it tells me the type is transient while i got it ( populated the dropdown list) from the DB i get :

```js
WARN  UnresolvedEntityInsertActions - HHH000437: Attempting to save one or more entities that have a non-nullable association with an unsaved transient entity. The unsaved transient entity must be saved in an operation prior to saving these dependent entities.
 Unsaved transient entity: ([jpa.project.model.DemTypeDemande#0])
 Dependent entities: ([[jpa.project.model.DemDemande#8950]])
 Non-nullable association(s): ([jpa.project.model.DemDemande.demTypeDemande])
```

Controller :

```js
 @RequestMapping(value = "/demandes/manage",method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView manageUsers(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
  ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();           
 //----1.ADD USER
     model.addObject("demUser", new DemUser()); 
 //----2.ADD TYPES
  List<DemTypeDemande> listTypes = service.getTypeDemandes();
  model.addObject("listTypes", listTypes);    
 //----3.ADD DEMANDE
      DemDemande demande = new DemDemande();
   model.addObject("DemDemande", demande); 
 
 model.setViewName("managedemandes");
  return model; }
  
 @RequestMapping(value = "/demandes/actionadddemande", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String actionadduser(HttpServletRequest request ,@ModelAttribute("demTypeDemande") DemTypeDemande typeDemande,@ModelAttribute ("DemDemande") DemDemande demande , BindingResult result) {
  demande.setDemUser(service.getUserByUsername(service.getConnectedUsername(request)));
  demande.setDemTypeDemande(typeDemande);
        service.addDemande(demande);
 return "redirect:/demandes/manage";
 }
```

JSP :

```html
        <form:form action="actionadddemande" method="POST" commandName="DemDemande">
        <table>
                    <form:hidden path="idDemande" />
                     <form:hidden path="demUser"  />          
        <tr>
    <td>Types :</td>
    <td>
  <form:select path="demTypeDemande">
         <form:options items="${listTypes}"  itemValue="idTypeDemande" itemLabel="libTypeDemande"></form:options>
    </form:select></td>
</tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Save"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </form:form>
```

Type entity relation :

```js
 //bi-directional many-to-one association to DemDemande
 @OneToMany(mappedBy="demTypeDemande")
 private List<DemDemande> demDemandes;
```

Demande entity relation :

```html
 //bi-directional many-to-one association to DemTypeDemande
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
 @JoinColumn(name="ID_TYPE_DEMANDE")
 private DemTypeDemande demTypeDemande;
```

Comment: Does the `typeDemande` that you are set to `demande` has a non-null id field in the `POST` method

Comment: @Vishnu it's supposed to have a non-null id yeah , but i think it's not getting , i just want to get the selected object or it's id so i can at least load a persisted object from DB so i can get over this ..